# Passing data to child component is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, undefined, react-props

```
     ***Menucomponent.js***
```

I have a  on which onClick handler is working and sending dish detail to getDish function.which is passing data as a props to Cart component.

But it not working .Dishdetail is showing in menu component when i console.log it but won't show on cart component and undefined error.

```
          <div className="row">
      {this.props.dishes.map((dish, index) => {
        return (
          <Card
            className="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 m-3 text-white"
            style={{ height: "400px", backgroundColor: "#1A0301" }}
          >
            <CardBody>
              <CardTitle>{this.props.dishes[index].name}</CardTitle>

              <CardSubtitle></CardSubtitle>
            </CardBody>

      <img
              height="30%"
              src={this.props.dishes[index].image}
              alt={this.props.dishes[index].description}
            />

            <button className="bg-dark text-white mt-4 " width="100">
              <CardText>
                Serve for - {this.props.dishes[index].serving}
              </CardText>
            </button>
            <CardBody>
              <CardSubtitle>
                $$$ -{this.props.dishes[index].price}
              </CardSubtitle>
            </CardBody>
            <button
              className="text-white m-2 p-2 "
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#FDA50F" }}
              onClick={() => this.getDish(this.props.dishes[index])}
            >
              Order Now
            </button>
            <button
              className="text-white m-2 p-2 "
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#FDA50F" }}
            >
              <Link to="/cart" className="text-white">
                Check cart
              </Link>
            </button>
          </Card>
```

**function which handle onclick event**

```
getDishId(dishdetail) 
  {
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
          <div className="container-fluid">{console.log(dishdetail.name)}</div>

          <Cart dishdetail={this.props.dishdetail} />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
   }
```

`CartComponent.js`

```
const Cart = (props) => {
     return (
       <React.Fragment>
         <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src="/assests/images/buffet.png" />
              <CardBody>
                  <CardTitle>{console.log(props.dishdetail)}</CardTitle>

                    <CardText>{props.description}</CardText>
                           <Button>Button</Button>
               </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
     );
};
```

Comment: Can you share the how getDishId is been called? Seems you are missing the binding for function.If dishDetail is same try this: <Cart dishdetail={dishdetail} /> in getDishId function

Comment: **this is how i'm calling getDishid**                                                                     
 < buttonon Click={() => this.getDish(this.props.dishes[index])}/>                              
 **Here i'm binding getDishId**                                                                                         
  this.getDish = this.getDish.bind(this);

Comment: are this 2 different function getDishId & getDish?

Comment: no i changed name

Comment: No getDish and getDishid same function.i just changed the name.kindly guide me?